# Синхронный вывод в консоль

Tags: java, многопоточность, консоль

Здравствуйте, есть два потока. Каждый должен выводить в консоль 10 строк, в каждой строке по 5 символов.
Например:

```
00000
11111
00000
11111
```

и так далее.

Главное чтобы работало все синхронно.
Никак не получается оседлать `System.out`.
Как добиться синхронизации ? Пробовал и метод создавать с модификатором `syncronized` и `join()` использовал.

Comment: Что имеете в виду под работало все синхронно? В строке вывода есть информация о том, какой поток выводит? Приведите свой код.

Comment: Сначала первый поток печает 5 нулей, затем второй печатает 5 единичек и так 20 раз (то есть каждый по 10 строк выводит)

Comment: используйте wait и notifyAll, синхронизируйтесь по System.out

Comment: Пытался, все равно не получается, ведь System.out не печатает сразу, а буферизирует данные.

Comment: тогда выкладывайте код, а там уже посмотрим.

Comment: Вы уж определитесь: либо многопоточно, либо одно за одним...

Comment: flush попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Out0000011111 {

//будет хранить какому потоку можно осуществлять вывод
private static AtomicReference<MyThread> link = new AtomicReference<>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    //для одновременного запуска потоков делаем защелку
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    MyThread thread1 = new MyThread(false, latch);
    MyThread thread2 = new MyThread(true, latch);

    //пусть каждый поток имеет ссылку на другого
    thread1.setOtherThread(thread2);
    thread2.setOtherThread(thread1);

    link.compareAndSet(null, thread1); //инициализация

    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();

    //на всякий случай подождем чтоб оба на защелке зависли
    Thread.sleep(1000);

    //запуск обоих потоков
    latch.countDown();
}


public static class MyThread extends Thread {
    private boolean flag;   //флаг того что именно печатать
    private CountDownLatch latch;
    private MyThread otherThread;

    public MyThread(boolean flag, CountDownLatch latch) {
        this.flag = flag;
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    void setOtherThread(MyThread thread) {
        this.otherThread = thread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
        try {
            //ждем на защелке
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            //крутимся в цикле пока не сможем напечатать
            while (true) {
                //печатаем только если разрешено
                if (link.get() == MyThread.this) {
                    if (flag) {
                        System.out.println("11111");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("00000");
                    }
                    link.compareAndSet(this, otherThread);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}}
```